# How to track users who access an app three times a week in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have an IOS app that is being tracked, and I'm looking to find unique users who use the app 3 or more times a week. I am able to find users who logged three sessions in a particular week, but I'd like to find users who log three sessions **every** week since a given start period.

Similarly, I'd like to find the number of users who use the app > 1 time a week and one and > 1 time a month.

Is this possible through Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has a report called "Frequency and Recency" that does what you want.  Here is the [help page for it](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1144427?hl=en):

> This report lets you see the level of user interest in your site (and by extension your products or services) from the standpoint of how frequently visitors return to your site within a time frame (once, twice, ten times), and how many days go by before they return to your site (do they tend to visit once a week or once a month). Statistics are calculated per unique visitor.

It can be accessed from "Audience" -> "Behavior" -> "Frequency and Recency".    Here is a screenshot from one of my sites.   I had 654 visitors that returned 3 or more times this week.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not take advantage of the new Cohort Analysis (Audience -> Cohort Analysis) in Google Analytics? It will generate a report that looks like this:

[image]

Great way to track user retention. Just select it as you metric. And you have a few other metrics to play with as well. This tool is still in beta some some other things are limited but for what you would use it for its more then enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cohort Analysis in Google Analytics to track unique users who use the app 3 or more times a week. A cohort is a set of users who share the same characteristics. Cohort analysis breaks users into related groups making it easy
to track retention, engagement and how users react to your app. It leads you to find the gaps, look for behavioral differences, appropriate time and way to execute your future campaigns and ask relevant questions.
The most important things you should be aware of are:

- Cohort Type
- Cohort Size
- Metric